# column name cannot be null

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, forms

This is a part of the code from my form application in C# and MySQL:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MySQL_CRUD
{
    class DbStudent
    {
        public static MySqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            string sql = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=student";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(sql);
            try 
            { 
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("MySQL Connection! \n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            return con;
        }

        public static void AddStudent(Student std)
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO student_table VALUES (NULL, @StudentName, @StudentReg, @StudentClass, @StudentSection, NULL)";
            MySqlConnection con = GetConnection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = std;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = std.Name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentReg", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = std.Reg;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentClass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = std.Class;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentSection", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = std.Section;
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Added successfully.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Student not inserted. \n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        public static void UpdateStudent(Student std, string id)
        {
            string sql = "UPDATE student_table SET Name = @StudentName, Reg = @StudentReg, Class = @StudentClass, Section = @StudentSection";
            MySqlConnection con = GetConnection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = std.Name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentReg", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = std.Reg;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentClass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = std.Class;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentSection", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = std.Section;
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Updated successfully.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Student not updated. \n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        public static void DeleteStudent(string id)
        {
            string sql = "DELETE FROM student_table WHERE ID = @StudentID";
            MySqlConnection con = GetConnection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Deleted successfully.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Student not deleted. \n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        public static void DisplayAndSearch(string query, DataGridView dgv)
        {
            string sql = query;
            MySqlConnection con = GetConnection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(tbl);
            dgv.DataSource = tbl;
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

When I run the program, and I fill the information needed to insert a Student, it shows me the error:

Student not inserted.
Column "Name" cannot be null

If I go to the database and declare all the elements as Null, then I will be able to insert a Student, but all of its elements will be null.

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: Always specify the column names in `INSERT` statements. You'll save yourself a lot of headaches. You're probably dealing with a column order issue, and considering you have `NULL`s explicitly specified in the `VALUES` clause, there's an especially good chance of that. Without seeing your schema, we're in the dark. You should show that.

Comment: Could you please add what your database table looks like? I'm guessing the issue might have to do with your SQL insert statement `string sql = "INSERT INTO student_table VALUES (NULL, @StudentName, @StudentReg, @StudentClass, @StudentSection, NULL)";`

Comment: You are also adding `@StudentID` parameter but it is absent from your `INSERT` statement

Comment: By the way, your `UPDATE` statement doesn't have a `WHERE` clause, so you are going to update all records from your table, which is probably not what you want

Comment: the database is like this:              ID Name Reg Class Section CreateAt